# CMake commands list for C/C++

Tags: c, build, cmake, qmake

I usually work with `qmake` for my `C` and `C++` projects but recently thought to learn `CMake`. A nice thing about `qmake` is that they have a variable reference here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html

I was searching for something similar for `CMake` but could not find one :( . Can someone please point me to one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this one fit your needs:

- http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html ?

I recently set up a sample project for cmake. Probably it helps you to get startet:

- https://github.com/moooeeeep/cmake_sample

Comment: OMG you are awesome! How did I not find it :|

Answer (score 0):

The path to the cmake reference manual changed to http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html